# How to switch displays with lwjgl

Tags: screen, buffer, panel, lwjgl

I am wondering how you would switch displays in lwjgl. Do you do swapBuffers(name_of_display)? What I mean is theres a menu screen, and I want to switch to an options screen without closing the display window, just the panel inside the window.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean? You could just render the menu in the same display and then toggle between rendering the game (or what it is) and rendering the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of my game containers which handles menu's maybe you can get something usefull out of it.

```
package catt.main;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import catt.gameMode.Arcade;
import catt.gameMode.Campaign;
import catt.gameMode.Editor;
import catt.gameMode.gameMode;
import catt.gameMode.menu.ArcadeMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.CampaignMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.ExitMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.ExitToMainMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.LoadScreen;
import catt.gameMode.menu.MainMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.editor.EditorMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.editor.LoadMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.editor.OverwriteMenu;
import catt.gameMode.menu.editor.SaveMenu;



public class Game {

    enum GameState{
        GAME, MENU;
    }
    enum GameType{

        //Gamemodes
        ARCADE, CAMPAIGN, EDITOR, LOADING,

        //Menus
        M_MAIN, M_ARCADE, M_EDITOR, M_EXIT, M_EXIT_MAIN, M_CAMPAIGN, M_LOAD, M_SAVE, M_OVERWRITE;
    }
    public static gameMode gameMode;
    public static gameMode gameMenu;

    private static GameState GameState;

    private static GameType GameType;
    private static GameType lastGameType;
    private static GameType lastMenu;

    private Boolean isRunning = true;

    private static String saveFile;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public Game(){
        GameState = GameState.MENU;
        GameType = GameType.M_MAIN;
        lastMenu = GameType;
    }

    //Gameloop
    public void isRunning(){
        gameLoad();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()&&isRunning != false){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            //Subloops
            escape();
            update();


            Display.update(); 
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        setGameType("M_EXIT");
    }

    /**
     * Sets the gameMode or gameMenu to the right active state and loads it.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void gameLoad(){

        if(GameState == GameState.GAME){
            if(GameType == GameType.ARCADE){
                gameMode = new Arcade();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.CAMPAIGN){
                gameMode = new Campaign();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.EDITOR){
                gameMode = new Editor();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.LOADING){
                gameMode = new LoadScreen();
            }
            gameMode.load();
        }
        else if(GameState == GameState.MENU){
            if(GameType == GameType.M_MAIN){
                gameMenu = new MainMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_ARCADE){
                gameMenu = new ArcadeMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_CAMPAIGN){
                gameMenu = new CampaignMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_EDITOR){
                gameMenu = new EditorMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_EXIT){
                gameMenu = new ExitMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_SAVE){
                gameMenu = new SaveMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_LOAD){
                gameMenu = new LoadMenu();
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_OVERWRITE){
                gameMenu = new OverwriteMenu(saveFile);
            }else if(GameType == GameType.M_EXIT_MAIN){
                gameMenu = new ExitToMainMenu();
            }
            gameMenu.load();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the menu should be opened or closed if the escape button is pressed;
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void escape(){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
            if(Keyboard.next()){
                if(GameState == GameState.MENU&&GameType == GameType.M_MAIN){
                    setGameType("M_EXIT");
                }else if(GameState == GameState.MENU&&GameType != GameType.M_MAIN){
                    if(GameType == GameType.M_SAVE
                            ||GameType == Game.GameType.M_LOAD){
                        setGameType("M_LAST");
                    }else{                      
                        setState("GAME");
                    }
                }else if(GameState == GameState.GAME){

                    if(GameType == GameType.ARCADE){
                        setGameType("M_ARCADE");
                    }else if(GameType == GameType.CAMPAIGN){
                        setGameType("M_CAMPAIGN");
                    }else if(GameType == GameType.EDITOR){
                        setGameType("M_EDITOR");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Switches the game state to the asigned state (Menu or Game)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void update(){
        if(GameState == GameState.MENU){
            gameMenu.update();
            gameMenu.render();
        }else if(GameState == GameState.GAME){
            gameMode.update();
            gameMode.render();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void setState(String state){
        if(state == "GAME"){
            GameState = GameState.GAME;
            GameType = lastGameType;
        }
        else if(state == "MENU"){
            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = lastMenu;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sets the (enum) GameType and GameState to the next GameType/State.
     * @param type
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void setGameType(String type){
        //Gamemodes
        if (type == "ARCADE") {

            GameState = GameState.GAME;
            GameType = GameType.ARCADE;
            lastGameType = GameType.ARCADE;
        } 

        else if (type ==  "CAMPAIGN") {

            GameState = GameState.GAME;
            GameType = GameType.CAMPAIGN;
            lastGameType = GameType.CAMPAIGN;
        } 

        else if (type ==  "EDITOR") {

            GameState = GameState.GAME;
            GameType = GameType.EDITOR;
            lastGameType = GameType.EDITOR;
        }

        //Menus
        else if (type ==  "M_MAIN") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_MAIN;
            lastMenu = GameType.M_MAIN;
        }

        else if (type ==  "M_ARCADE") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_ARCADE;
            lastMenu = GameType.M_ARCADE;
        }

        else if (type ==  "M_CAMPAIGN") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_CAMPAIGN;
            lastMenu = GameType.M_CAMPAIGN;
        }
        else if (type ==  "M_EDITOR") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_EDITOR;
            lastMenu = GameType.M_EDITOR;
        }
        else if (type ==  "M_LOAD") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_LOAD;
        }
        else if (type ==  "M_SAVE") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_SAVE;
        }
        else if (type == "M_OVERWRITE"){
            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_OVERWRITE;
        }

        else if(type == "M_EXIT_MAIN"){
            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_EXIT_MAIN;
        }
        else if (type ==  "M_EXIT") {

            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = GameType.M_EXIT;
        }
        else if(type == "M_LAST"){
            GameState = GameState.MENU;
            GameType = lastMenu;
        }
        gameLoad();
    }
```